# Set widest menu item size to select menu width

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui `Select` and `MenuItem`. I want to set longest menu item width as select menu width.

Here is my code.

```
const renderMenuItem = (option: any) => {
        const { value: optValue, label, icon, onClick = () => { } } = option;
        return (
            <MenuItem
                key={optValue}
                className={classes.menuItem}
                value={optValue}
                onClick={onClick}
            >
                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>{icon} <p>{label}</p></div>
            </MenuItem>
        );
    }


    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
         <Select
             value={value}
             autoWidth={true}
             className={classes.select}
          >
          {options.map(renderMenuItem)}
         </Select>
    </FormControl>
```

css classess as follows

```
       formControl: {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            minWidth: 213,
            padding: "0",
            height: 35
        }
        select: {
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center"
        },
        menuItem: {
            color: "#222228",
            fontSize: "13px",
            letterSpacing: 0,
            lineHeight: "24px",
            display: "flex"
        }
```

However the output gives as follows.

[image]

But what I want is to increase the width of the Select menu as widest menu item as follows. Here I give fixed width to Select Menu. But I cannot used that approach as length of the Menu Item are unknown.

[image]